# Jacobson radical of an exterior algebra

Tags: ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ and suppose $\dim(V)=\infty$ with basis $\{e_1,e_2,\dots\}$. Let $G$ be the exterior algebra of $V$. How to calculate the Jacobson radical $J(G)$?

(A basis for $G$ is $1$ and all "monomials" $e_{i_1}\wedge e_{i_2}\cdots\wedge e_{i_n}$, where $n>0$ and $i_{1}<i_{2}<\cdots<i_{n}$ and multiplication $e_i\wedge e_j=-e_j\wedge e_i$)

I appreciate any hint. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't the ideal generated by $\langle e_1, e_2, \dots \rangle$ the only maximal left ideal? If it is, it coincides with $J(G)$, since the latter is the intersection of all maximal left ideals.

Comment: @peterag Yes, I thinks this is true. However, proving directly that this ideal is the only maximal seems a lot simpler. I'l make this into an answer.

Comment: @lisyarus oops I deleted my comment: here is something like it for history's sake: "any element with non-constant term is nilpotent, agree?"

Comment: @peterag Oops, I retreat: my reasoning was wrong.

Comment: @rschwieb FWIW I had in mind that the Jacobson radical is the set of left/right quasi-regular elements. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiregular_element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not hard to see that anything with a zero constant term is nilpotent .  (As you expand powers, the grades of monomials can only increase, until every one contains the square of a basis vector.)

Then $c+x$ is a unit for every nonzeroconstant $c$ and element $x$ with constant $0$, because $x$ is nilpotent and $c$ is a unit commuting with $x$.

So for every element, if it is not a unit, it is contained in $(e_1,e_.2\ldots)$, which is additively closed. Since the nonunits are closed under addition, the ring is a local ring. Therefore the Jacobson radical is exactly that ideal.

Comment: Every element with a zero constant term is in a subalgebra isomorphic to the exterior algebra of a finite dimensional vector space, so it is nilpotent.

Comment: One could generalize to algebras which are a filtered union of local algebras, I guess.

Comment: I think this is right (+1). Cheers!

Comment: Great! Thank you. I understand your answer.